# How To Have Character Slide Back and Forth Automatically and Infinitely?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm an ubernoob developing a game using SpriteKit from scratch and im trying to make a character that will slide back and forth off the sides of the screen (in landscape mode) until collision is detected with another node (that I will add later). Think of pong and how the paddle can move side to side except I want that movement to be completely automatic/infinite.

Side Note: I plan on having this character jump when the screen is touched but continue with the back and forth movement. idk if that makes a difference in your approach.

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. Show us what you have tried so far, no one will write the code for you from scratch.

Comment: @DávidPásztor not true, I do that all the time

Comment: ubernoobs dont have code to swtart with bc they dk wtf they r doing ;) i blame the tutorial sites bvc tghey show only how to do specific thing not teach how to apply to your own game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this answer isn't perfect but it's working for me right now so:

basically you touch the screen to spawn a boxd, and when the paddle touches the box some stuff happens (it stops moving):

```
import SpriteKit

// constants!

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

  // A little complicated, but basically we want to have a constant speed across all screen sizes
  var sliderSpeed: CGFloat { return self.size.width / 3 }

  var slider = SKSpriteNode()
  var sliderVelocity = CGFloat(0)
  var sliderIsContacted = false

  let boxMask = UInt32(2)
  let sliderMask = UInt32(4)

  // For use to contact slider
  func spawnBox(at pos: CGPoint) {
    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 45, height: 45))
    let shape = SKShapeNode(rect: rect)
    shape.fillColor = .green
    shape.position = pos

    let pb = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: rect.size)
    pb.categoryBitMask = boxMask
    pb.contactTestBitMask = sliderMask
    shape.physicsBody = pb

    addChild(shape)
  }

  func setupSlider() {
    sliderVelocity = sliderSpeed

    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 45, height: 10))
    let shape = SKShapeNode(rect: rect)
    shape.fillColor = .blue

    let pb = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: rect.size)
    pb.categoryBitMask = sliderMask
    pb.contactTestBitMask = boxMask
    pb.velocity.dx = sliderVelocity // moves our slider to the right!

    // A little complicated, but basically we want to have a spritenode, not a shapenode:
    slider = SKSpriteNode(texture: view!.texture(from: shape))
    slider.physicsBody = pb
    addChild(slider)
  }

  func setupWorld() {
    let pb = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame)
    pb.categoryBitMask = UInt32(0)
    self.physicsBody = pb

    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector.zero
  }


  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    setupSlider()
    setupWorld()
  }
}

// Game loop:
extension GameScene {

  // touchesBegan in iOS:
  override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    let location = event.location(in: self)
    spawnBox(at: location)
  }

  override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    let sliderPB = slider.physicsBody!
    let halfWidth = slider.size.width/2

    // move slider left when it reaches far right border:
    if sliderPB.velocity.dx > 0 {
      if slider.position.x >= (frame.maxX - halfWidth) {
        sliderVelocity = -sliderSpeed
      }
    }
      // move slider right when it reaches far left border:
    else {
      if slider.position.x <= (frame.minX + halfWidth) {
        sliderVelocity = sliderSpeed
      }
    }

    // Keep slider at constant rate:
    if sliderIsContacted == false {
      sliderPB.velocity.dx = sliderVelocity
    }
  }
  func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask + contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == sliderMask + boxMask {

      sliderIsContacted = true
      slider.physicsBody!.velocity.dx = 0 // stop slider
    }
  }
}
```

more complicated than it shoudl be, but I"m sdrunk so this is what I got :)

}hope it helps.